# facebook test scrape cache

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Does someone has an idea what does the "Test Scrape Cache" mean when sharing a link on Facebook?

[image: Test Scrape Cache]
<sub>(source: [zao.com](http://blog.zao.com/wp-content/themes/zaotheme/test.png))</sub>

My users try to share and re-share links (from facebook) - on the first share everything seems fine (text and image works fine) when someone tries to reshare a link - sometimes facebook displays the share with the text

My page is properly coded with OpenGraph tags.

Comment: I've never seen that before. Can you share the actual URL you're sharing?

Comment: The actual link is http://www.zao.com/bBffpT but is only happens after a re-share (the first one works good..)